# In MAXIMA, how do I get entire call stack printed?

Tags: stack-trace, trace, maxima, backtrace

Sorry if this is a novice question, but I couldn't find any documentation or other stackoverflow questions on this. I want to see entire stack trace of all maxima functions called in solving an expression or an equation. I tried trace, backtrace, and debugmode. Looked at different display and print functions, but none worked.

Example1:

```
(%i1) is(equal( (a+b)^2, a^2+b^2+2*a*b ));
(%o1) true
```

Example2:

```
(%i2) trace(factor);
(%o2) [factor]
(%i3) trace_options(factor, info);
(%o3) [info]
(%i4) factor( (x^2 - 7*x + 10) / (x - 5) );
1 Enter ?factor [(x^2-7*x+10)/(x-5)] -> true
1 Exit  ?factor x-2 -> true
(%o4) x-2
```

I want to see *every* intermediate step Maxima executed and its result in the derivation of these solutions or conclusions.Info on minutest level calls is even better.

Thanks,
RB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hack you can trace all functions listed in [builtins-list.txt](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/share/builtins-list.txt?format=raw):

```
l: read_list("builtins-list.txt") $
for e in l do errcatch(apply('trace, [e])) $
untrace(bfloatp) $ /* to limit output */
is(equal( (a+b)^2, a^2+b^2+2*a*b )) $
```

returns:

```
(%i5) is(equal( (a+b)^2, a^2+b^2+2*a*b )) $
                            2   2    2
1 Enter is [is(equal((a + b) , a  + b  + 2 a b))]
 1 Enter ratp [2]
 1 Exit  ratp false
 1 Enter ratp [b + a]
 1 Exit  ratp false
 1 Enter ratp [2]
 1 Exit  ratp false
 1 Enter ratp [b + a]
 1 Exit  ratp false
 1 Enter ratp [2]
 1 Exit  ratp false
 1 Enter ratp [a]
 1 Exit  ratp false
 1 Enter ratp [2]
 1 Exit  ratp false
 1 Enter ratp [b]
 1 Exit  ratp false
                      2
 1 Enter setp [(b + a) ]
 1 Exit  setp false
                   2            2
 1 Enter subvarp [b  + 2 a b + a ]
 1 Exit  subvarp false
                   2            2
 1 Enter subvarp [b  + 2 a b + a ]
 1 Exit  subvarp false
                         2    2            2
 1 Enter ratsimp [(b + a)  - b  - 2 a b - a ]
                       2    2            2
  1 Enter ratp [(b + a)  - b  - 2 a b - a ]
  1 Exit  ratp false
                              2    2            2
  1 Enter totaldisrep [(b + a)  - b  - 2 a b - a ]
                             2    2            2
  1 Exit  totaldisrep (b + a)  - b  - 2 a b - a
  1 Enter ratdisrep [0]
   1 Enter ratp [0]
   1 Exit  ratp true
  1 Exit  ratdisrep 0
 1 Exit  ratsimp 0
 1 Enter facts []
 1 Exit  facts []
 1 Enter niceindices [0]
 1 Exit  niceindices 0
 1 Enter constantp [0]
  1 Enter numberp [0]
   1 Enter ratnump [0]
   1 Exit  ratnump true
  1 Exit  numberp true
 1 Exit  constantp true
 1 Enter rectform [0]
 1 Exit  rectform 0
 1 Enter sign [0]
 1 Exit  sign zero
1 Exit  is true
1 Enter concat [, %o, 5]
1 Exit  concat %o5
1 Enter concat [, %i, 5]
1 Exit  concat %i5
1 Enter concat [, %i, 6]
1 Exit  concat %i6
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for my purpose. I was guessing and adding several functions to the trace, but didn't result in what I wanted. However, I was expecting maxima either (1) will expand (a+b)^2 to a^2+b^2+2*a*b  (or) (2) factor a^2+b^2+2*a*b to (a+b)^2 and then compare lhs and rhs to find their equality. It appears ratexpand() and factor() are not called at all and totaldisrep & ratdisrep are called by ratsimp and somehow concluded lhs and rhs are equal. But thanks for this hack, it gave me insight into which functions I should focus on.